# How to create mock for custom function using phpmock

Tags: php, function, mocking, phpunit

Phpmock is not working when a we included custom lib function. I have attached sample code here.
The getFirstName() function return "Steven", When it called form getName function.

**phpmock\test\indexTest.php**

```
<?php
  namespace testing;
  require_once(TEST_ROOT_DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php');
  $cwDir = dirname(__FILE__);
  $requireFile = str_replace('\test','',$cwDir).'\index.php';
  require_once($requireFile);
  use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
  use phpmock\MockBuilder;
  use phpmock\functions\FixedValueFunction;
  class indexText extends TestCase {
    public function testGetName(){
      $lo_builder =  new MockBuilder();
        $lo_builder->setNamespace(__NAMESPACE__)
          ->setName("getFirstName")
          ->setFunctionProvider(new FixedValueFunction('Lee'));            
         $lo_mock = $lo_builder->build();           
        $lo_mock->enable();
        var_dump(getFirstName());      
        $result = getName();
        $this->assertEquals('Lee mark',$result);
        $lo_mock->disable();
    }
  }
```

**phpmock/index.php**

```
<?php 
  require_once('inc/lib.php');

  function getName(){
   return getFirstName().' '.getLastName();
  }
?>
```

**phpmock/inc/lib.php**

```
<?php 
  function getFirstName(){
    return 'Steven';
   }
  function getLastName(){
    return 'mark';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Lee mark'
+'Steven mark'

Comment: Of course it returns 'Steven'. The only statement in that function is "return 'Steven';" Am I missing something?

Comment: use `/` instead of `\\` when replacing \test

Comment: Thanks Klutt, I am enabling  $lo_mock->enable(); So that i am expecting Lee as when i called the getFirstName() function.

Comment: Thanks for Inarilo.  When i have changed the source  code in phpmock/index.php file as function getName(){
   return \testing\getFirstName().' '.getLastName();
  }, my test case pass. But i don't want to change the source code of my project. I like to create a mock  for custom function without disturbing the exiting source code.

Comment: I am trying to use phpmock for my one of the Php project. 85% of code has been written in procedure oriented way. (function with include/require files). I have attached the sample(similar with sample function) source code source code https://github.com/pilathraj/phpmock here.